# Three ways to read a number for a BitInputStream

Tags: java, comparative-review, bitwise, serialization

I'm trying to learn how to write more readable code without introducing easily avoidable performance killers.

This is part of a `BitInputStream` Java class I'm experimenting with. There are code parts before and after this provided segment to read less than 8 bits from `iBuffer` if data is not aligned to bytes - that's why `aNumberOfBits` is needed to know how many bits have to be read later on.

I think variant 3 below is best when implemented in Java, but variant 1 may be worth the more complex formula for slightly better (theoretical) performance in C for realtime applications.

Variant 1:

```
int i = aNumberOfBits / 8;
aNumberOfBits -= i * 8;
for (; i > 0; --i) {
   iBuffer = iIs.read();
   if (iBuffer == -1) {
      throw new EOFException();
   }
   value = (value << 8) | iBuffer;
}
```

Variant 2 (obviously worse performant on most CPUs?):

```
for (int i = aNumberOfBits / 8; i > 0; --i) {
   iBuffer = iIs.read();
   if (iBuffer == -1) {
      throw new EOFException();
   }
   value <<= 8;
   value |= iBuffer;
   aNumberOfBits -= 8;
}
```

Variant 3:

```
for (int i = aNumberOfBits / 8; i > 0; --i) {
   iBuffer = iIs.read();
   if (iBuffer == -1) {
      throw new EOFException();
   }
   value = (value << 8) | iBuffer;
}
aNumberOfBits %= 8;
```

Now what about variant 2: should `aNumberOfBits` be decremented by 8 in the loop for a better understanding why it is decremented? (And isn't shifting `value` and then ORing the next part of data even more complicated to read than doing it in one step?)

Comment: Added [tag:comparative-review] since you mentioned 'variants' of your code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are so concerned about performance, then you should run a benchmark.  I would bet that there is no appreciable difference in performance, as the task is going to be IO-bound rather than CPU-bound.  A much bigger impact on performance would be, for example, whether the input stream is buffered.  Therefore, you should just pick the code that looks the best.  I personally prefer a variant of variant 3.

It seems that you are interested in the values of `value` and `aNumberOfBits` after the loop.  Since `i` is unimportant, let's just ditch it.  Also, `iBuffer` seems to be a temporary variable, so its scope should be limited to the loop.

Finally, let's get rid of the Hungarian notation!

```
for (; bitCount >= 8; bitCount -= 8) {
    int b = input.read();
    if (b == -1) {
        throw new EOFException();
    }
    value = (value << 8) | b;
}
```

What might make a performance impact is reading a `byte[]` array at once instead of a byte at a time.  Handling possible buffer underruns correctly would be a pain, though, so I don't recommend it here.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think about eliminating the `i` variable and to not use `iBuffer` because there is nothing going to be left on that variable! I'll add a variant 4...

Comment: I've rolled back Rev 4 → 3. Please don't change or add code to be reviewed.

Comment: Ok, so your answer is accepted because you eliminated my original problem. Don't know whether it is the perfect solution for everyone because the title was changed. Thank you again!